# How do I get/set Domino read status of messages via Domino COM Object?

Tags: api, com, lotus-domino

I have an application that interacts with Domino via the Domino COM object. I can send, find, delete messages without problem but getting/setting the unread status does not work. The Domino COM object has method to get the read status but it always come back as read. Anyone have a workaround that works? I've had no success with anything I've found searching online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually with some more research it looks like getting/setting the unread status through the COM API doesn't work. However using the [C++ API](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/cplus/3.0/lncpp30.nsf) would work - and I should be able to integrate this with my existing C# project as a managed C++ project.

Comment: Ended up finding the messages with com api, getting uid, pass that to a managed c++ function that opens the message database, finds the message by uid, gets the unread list from the database, refrshes it, then sees if the msg is in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Unread marks in Domino are a funny old beast. They're derived from multiple sources: whilst you have an internal table of Notes IDs within a specific NSF, you also have an "unread journal" stored in the local Notes client's CACHE.DSK file.

All recent versions of Notes (i.e. in the last 8 / 9 years) move this unread table within the Notes client (to DESKTOP.DSK I think), and also make them server-aware, so that APIs can get a handle on unread marks.

Unfortunately, this means that you're probably out of luck with things like COM but as you've found, the C++ API should be OK.
[IBM: The Architecture of Unread Marks in Lotus Notes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27002920)